# Connecting to self-hosted PeerJS Server - Angular

Tags: angular, heroku, webrtc, peerjs

I'm attempting to connect to my peerServer hosted on Heroku. I have used the 'cloud' peerServer provider by PeerJs and my connection works, however, I need my own ssl server. From what I understand my peerServer is working correctly. - >  https://asphericpeerjs.herokuapp.com/

I have modified the code according to the peerjs API documentation, however, according to the chrome console it is still calling http://0.peerjs.com/.../ect/ect...

```
this.peer = new Peer([], [{ host : 'https://asphericpeerjs.herokuapp.com' }]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.mypeerid = this.peer.id;
        }, 3000);
```

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are not necessary, do it like this:

```
this.peer = new Peer({ host : 'https://asphericpeerjs.herokuapp.com' });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.mypeerid = this.peer.id;
        }, 3000);
```